# How to restrict access to user for particular store in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, plugin, permissions, user-roles

I have a requirement where multiple stores are created under one website.

Now, I want to create role so that role has access only to the particular store.

For e.g. If there is role Dell Manager so role should have access to Dell Store only.

In `System > User Roles > Add new role > Role Resource`. I can see `store` option. But on expanding it I am not able to see list of store in Magento that I have configured.

[image]

I have explored on it and found a plugin which is supporting it. [LINK](https://www.aitoc.com/en/magento_2_advanced_permissions.html)

Is there any other way I can do this functionality without third party plugin/extension?

Comment: Restricting admin users to scopes is a enterprise feature so you have to go with some sort of module to achieve this functionality. Only way to avoid third parties would be to write your own but i dont think this is something you achieve with just a few lines of code. We are looking for something similar so if i find an easy solution i will post it here.